# Upgrade 18.04 fails with failed to download repository information

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, repository

I choose Select Best Server option in the software and updates -> Ubuntu Software -> Download From -> Other.  When I click Close it comes back with

```
The information about available software is out-of-date
```

I click Reload and it gives

```
Failed to download repository information
```

Under Details it shows a tiny window with this error message:

```
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu/dists/artful/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80], E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful InRelease' is not signed., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386', W:An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AA16FCBCA621E701, W:GPG error: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC, E:The repository 'http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease' is no longer signed., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>, W:An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05, W:An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable bionic InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8E6DA8B4E158C569 Samuli Seppänen (OpenVPN Technologies, Inc) <samuli@openvpn.net>
```

What do I have to do to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04?

Edit:

I was able to upgrade to 20.04.6 using `sudo apt dist-upgrade` followed by `sudo do-release-upgrade`.  It's the UI upgrade path that is broken.

Comment: You have a paste for a different release (17.10) in your question?  You mention using 18.04 and wanting to move to 20.04, in which case why is there a source for an EOL release present?    Ubuntu 17.10 or the 2017-October release is EOL (*end-of-life*). https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/07/19/ubuntu-17-10-artful-aardvark-end-of-life-reached-on-july-19-2018/   Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but note it's no longer supported on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It's 18.04, not 17.  I don't see a 17 in my post.

Comment: Your PPA is `artful` (17.10). That's what @guiverc was referring to. Do not mix sources for different releases of Ubuntu. That's an easy way to break your system.  The 403 error means that PPA no longer exists anyway. Delete that PPA, and be prepared to uninstall all packages from that PPA if you encounter a package version conflict. The use of `dist-upgrade` is only part of a release-upgrade, don't forget to do the rest.

Comment: I have no idea where it's getting the artful release PPA from.  This has always been a Ubuntu 18 system.